# PHP MySQL connection on a drupal-7 site

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I have a Drupal-7 local website and I have a form/button in an article. I want when the button is clicked to be able and track the username and the password of those who clicked the button. The form html code is the following:

```
<form action="mysql-query.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Press(this)">
    <input type="text" name="email" style="display:none;">
    <input type="submit" value="Press here" id="test">
</form>
```

I have created from phpmyadmin a new column on users table called button, which is an Int(1) with default value=0 and the mysql-query.php file contains this code:

```
<?php
$_POST["email"];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "drupal";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
}


mysql_select_db($dbname);

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET button='1' WHERE email=loggedInMail");

$output = mysql_query("SELECT name, mail FROM users WHERE button='1'");

?>
```

I clicked on the button, and checked users table, but all the users I created have a button 0 value. Any ideas of what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

change line:

$_POST["email"];

to

$postemail = $_POST["email"];

change line:

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET button='1' WHERE email=loggedInMail");

to

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET button='1' WHERE email='".$postemail."'");

Comment: I checked button column again, but the admin user has still a  button value of 0, after I refreshed the page and clicked on the button again

Comment: ok so you also have: style="display:none;" in your text input field which is going to make it difficult to enter any information

Comment: then you should use a hidden input field instead:
<input type="hidden" name="email" value='xyz@abc.com'>

in either case you need the value='xyz@abc.com' attribute or nothing will pass back with the form

Comment: and have $_POST['email']; back again? Should I use this value at my php file? or somewhere in my phpmyadmin? I am not that experienced